# ORA-06550: line 5, column 16: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
BEGIN 
  dbms_stats.set_table_prefs 
    ( ownname => 'SALES_MART', 
      tabname =>  SELECT DISTINCT (table_name) 
                  FROM all_part_tables 
                  WHERE OWNER = 'SALES_MART', 
      pname   => 'INCREMENTAL', 
      pvalue  =>'TRUE' 
    ); 
END;
```

> ORA-06550: line 5, column 16: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( - + case mod new not null continue avg count current exists max min
>   prior sql stddev sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp
>   interval date pipe
>
> & - + ; / at for mod remainder rem and or group having intersect minus
>   order start union where connect || multiset

Comment: Why are you passing select statement as argument?

Comment: how can i pass it?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. It just wastes other peoples' time.

Answer (score 1):

`DBMS_STATS.SET_TABLE_PREFS` procedure accepts table name as an argument. You can't pass select statement.

I assume that you want to execute this procedure for all tables, where the owner is `SALES_MART`, so in this case, you can use the cursor and invoke this procedure in loop:

```
BEGIN

  FOR part_tables_rec in (
    SELECT DISTINCT table_name
    FROM all_part_tables
    WHERE OWNER = 'SALES_MART'
  ) LOOP

    dbms_stats.set_table_prefs ( 
      ownname =>'SALES_MART', 
      tabname => part_tables_rec.table_name,
      pname   => 'INCREMENTAL',
      pvalue  => 'TRUE' );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: ORA-20001: BIN$ABDJN0XVIALGU4GK/AOIFQ==$0 is an invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 45404
ORA-06512: at line 9

Comment: BEGIN

  FOR part_tables_rec in (
    SELECT DISTINCT table_name
    FROM all_part_tables
    WHERE OWNER = 'ARDENT'
  ) LOOP

    dbms_stats.set_table_prefs ( 
      ownname =>'ARDENT', 
      tabname => part_tables_rec.table_name,
      pname   => 'INCREMENTAL',
      pvalue  => 'TRUE' );
  END LOOP;
END;

Comment: `BIN$ABDJN0XVIALGU4GK/AOIFQ==$0` is the identifier of a dropped table in the Recycle bin. You need to add a WHERE clause to filter those out e.g. `where table_name not like 'BIN$%'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
begin
  for p_tab_name_list in (SELECT owner,table_name
                            FROM all_part_tables
                           WHERE owner = 'SALES_MART'
                             and table_name not like 'BIN$%'
                           group by owner,table_name
                          ) LOOP
    dbms_stats.set_table_prefs ( 
      ownname => p_tab_name_list.owner, 
      tabname => p_tab_name_list.table_name,
      pname   => 'INCREMENTAL',
      pvalue  => 'TRUE' );
  end loop;
end;
```